# TeamCity doesn't release file locks after a cancelled build

Tags: build, teamcity, file-locking

We are using an Enterprise version of TeamCity 2017. We experience an issue that is reproduced like this:

1. Start a build
2. Immediately cancel it
3. Start a build

at this point, an exception in TeamCity occurs, that looks like this:

[image]

I investigated it, and found out that it is because of a file lock in the checkout directory. A solution was to just manually kill processes that lock files in a separate build step. But this step is not invoked when the build is cancelled **BEFORE THE FIRST BUILD STEP IS INVOKED**. So all in all, the locks are not released, and TeamCity can't perform a clean.

I tried using the Swabra plugin, but it seemingly has no effect (as if it is not even working)